# Decode an optional Dictionary without actual mapping in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, codable

I have a struct which contains an optional metaData field of type `[String: Any]?`. I'd like to parse a JSON to that struct and explicitly not map the dictionary but keep it as is.

```
struct MyObject: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let whatever: String
    let metaData: [String: Any]?

    enum CardKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case whatever
        case metaData
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CardKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        whatever = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .whatever)
        metaData = try container.decodeIfPresent([String: Any].self, forKey: .metaData)
    }
}
```

That code compiles and starts but fails at runtime. I guess that `[String: Any]` just is not an valid type I can use here. But how would I do it then?

Comment: Related: [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol).

Comment: `Decodable` was not designed with dynamic keys in mind. You can work around it, but the better approach is to define a `MyMetadata` struct with all possible metadata as optional properties

Answer (score 0):

I created a framework to decode/encode dictionaries.

[CodableDictionary](https://github.com/wieweb/CodableDictionary)

Install framework and replace

```
  let metaData: [String: Any]?
```

with

```
  let metaData: CodableDictionary?
```