# Parsing Nested JSON SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, codable

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
{
"results": {
    "AF": {
        "alpha3": "AFG",
        "currencyId": "AFN",
        "currencyName": "Afghan afghani",
        "currencySymbol": "؋",
        "id": "AF",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    "AI": {
        "alpha3": "AIA",
        "currencyId": "XCD",
        "currencyName": "East Caribbean dollar",
        "currencySymbol": "$",
        "id": "AI",
        "name": "Anguilla"
    }
}
```

}

My code :

```
class Results: Codable {
  let results: [Country]

  init(results: [Country]) {
    self.results = results
  }
}

class Country: Codable {

  let currencyId: String
  let currencyName: String
  let currencySymbol: String
  let id: String
  let name: String


  init(currencyId :String, currencyName: String, currencySymbol: String, id: String, name: String ) {

    self.currencyId = currencyId
    self.currencyName = currencyName
    self.currencySymbol = currencySymbol
    self.id = id
    self.name = name

  }
}
```

I have looked at Apple's Documentation on decoding nested structs, but I still do not understand how to do the different levels of the JSON properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993251/parsing-nested-json-in-swift-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the outlined value for the key `"results"`.

```
"results": {
    ...
}
```

`{...}` represents JSON object. A Swift `struct` (or `class` if you think it's better) would be appropriate for JSON object in some cases.

In other cases, Swift `Dictionary` may be more appropriate.

And each value of this JSON object takes this form:

```
{
    "alpha3": ...,
    "currencyId": ...,
    "currencyName": ...,
    "currencySymbol": ...,
    "id": ...,
    "name": ...
}
```

which matches your `Country`.

So, you just need to change the type of `results` in your `Results` class.

```
class Results: Codable {
    let results: [String: Country]

    init(results: [String: Country]) {
        self.results = results
    }
}
```

Having the same name (without case) for a property and its class might cause some confusion in the future, but I keep it as is as for now.

You can test it like this:

(Assuming to be tested in the Playground with modified `Results` and your `Country`.)

```
let jsonText = """
{
    "results": {
        "AF": {
            "alpha3": "AFG",
            "currencyId": "AFN",
            "currencyName": "Afghan afghani",
            "currencySymbol": "؋",
            "id": "AF",
            "name": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "AI": {
            "alpha3": "AIA",
            "currencyId": "XCD",
            "currencyName": "East Caribbean dollar",
            "currencySymbol": "$",
            "id": "AI",
            "name": "Anguilla"
        }
    }
}
"""
let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: jsonData)
    print(results) //-> __lldb_expr_1.Results
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```