# How to parse nested json? Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, codable

i have a local json string and i am trying to parse it but when i try to do so, i am constantly getting an error. I have also seen this error in nested dictionary but couldnt find an error.
Below is the json string

```
let jsonNestedString  = "{\"meta\":{\"page\":1,\"total_pages\":4,\"per_page\":10,\"total_records\" : 38}, \"reweries\":[\"id\":1234,\"name\":\"saintArnold\"},{\"id\":52892,\"name\":\"buffalo bayou\"]}"
```

i am doing this process via Codable and below is the struct i have created for the same

```
struct PagedBreweries:Codable{
    struct Meta:Codable{
        let page : Int
        let total_pages:Int
        let per_page:Int
        let total_records: Int
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case page
            case total_pages
            case per_page
            case total_records
        }
    }

    struct Brewery :Codable{
        let id:Int
        let name:String

    }
    let meta:Meta
    let breweries :[Brewery]
}
```

then this data is parsed to  a function  as below

```
    func jsonNested(){
    let jsonData = jsonNestedString.data(using: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data  = try! decoder.decode(PagedBreweries.Meta.self, from: jsonData!)
    print(data)
}
```

and when i try to build, the error i get is present in try! decoder.decode
command
and the error is

Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "page", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"page\", intValue: nil) (\"page\").", underlyingError: nil))

Could any one provide a solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This might not be the cause, but the `]age` part looks a little bit suspicious.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. You should always test your JSON on a validator like [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) before trying to use it.

Comment: i tried on a json validator and it confirms that this json is in fact  valid

Comment: This part is also not valid: `\"reweries\":[\"id\":1234,\"name\":\"saintArnold\"}`.

Comment: **Read** the error message, it's pretty descriptive: Character 64 is the region around `= 38`.Key/value pairs in JSON are always separated by **colon** (`:`). And about 20 characters later there is an opening brace missing after `:[`

Comment: vadian, there is an opening brace there

Comment: No, there is none. It must be `...\"reweries\":[{\"id\"...`. By the way there's also a `b` missing, you probably mean `\"breweries\"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is corrupt and you are decoding the wrong root object.

This is the **correct** JSON being decoded with your structs and conforming to the Swift naming convention

```
let jsonNestedString  = """
{"meta":{"page":1,"total_pages":4,"per_page":10,"total_records" : 38}, "breweries":[{"id":1234,"name":"saintArnold"},{"id":52892,"name":"buffalo bayou"}]}
"""

struct PagedBreweries : Codable {
    struct Meta : Codable {
        let page : Int
        let totalPages:Int
        let perPage:Int
        let totalRecords: Int
    }

    struct Brewery : Codable {
        let id:Int
        let name:String

    }
    let meta:Meta
    let breweries :[Brewery]
}

func jsonNested(){
    let jsonData = Data(jsonNestedString.utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let data  = try! decoder.decode(PagedBreweries.self, from: jsonData)
    print(data)
}

jsonNested()

// Printed result: 
// PagedBreweries(meta: __lldb_expr_1.PagedBreweries.Meta(page: 1, totalPages: 4, perPage: 10, totalRecords: 38), breweries: [__lldb_expr_1.PagedBreweries.Brewery(id: 1234, name: "saintArnold"), __lldb_expr_1.PagedBreweries.Brewery(id: 52892, name: "buffalo bayou")])
```

Comment: it finally worked, thank you so much for your time pal

Answer (score 3):

Correct json

```
{
    "meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "total_pages": 4,
        "per_page": 10,
        "total_records": 38
    },
    "reweries": [{
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "saintArnold"
    },
    {
    "id": 52892,
    "name": "buffalo bayou"
    }
    ]
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let reweries: [Rewery]
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let page, totalPages, perPage, totalRecords: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {  // snake case may be used 
        case age = "page"
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case perPage = "per_page"
        case totalRecords = "total_records"
    }
}

struct Rewery: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
  let jsonNestedString  = """
    {\"meta\":{\"page\":1,\"total_pages\":4,\"per_page\":10,\"total_records\":38}, \"reweries\":[{\"id\":1234,\"name\":\"saintArnold\"},{\"id\":52892,\"name\":\"buffalo bayou\"}]}
"""

  // or 

let jsonNestedString  = """

{
    "meta": {
        "page": 1,
        "total_pages": 4,
        "per_page": 10,
        "total_records": 38
    },
    "reweries": [{
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "saintArnold"
    },
    {
    "id": 52892,
    "name": "buffalo bayou"
    }
    ]
}


"""

do {

    let jsonData = jsonNestedString.data(using: .utf8)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data  = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData!)
    print(data)


} catch  {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: my json is valid i have tested on multiple sites but still gives the same error

Comment: also, you have changed the code, the above structures as you suggest are not nested

Comment: @vgvishesh23113 i don't know why you need the slashes , but i added them see edit.......

Comment: i need slashes to make it a valid string in swift

Comment: no you don't have to there is a multi line string with """str""" see edit...........

Comment: i know that now, didnt before but it shud still work right as slashes were suggessted by swift itself

Comment: if you use "" then you have too , but with """ escape them

Comment: still does not help with the error, any insights for that??

Comment: @vgvishesh23113 did you tried all answer content 
??

Comment: in that case i apologize, i might have changed something in your answer which didnt solve it. once again , thanks for the time and effort, much appreciated