# Extract and decode json data using Decodable in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I'm using an external framework for showing message list and detail screen.

Framework internal Message model which we can't modify:

```
public struct Message: Decodable, Encodable {
    public var id: String?
    public var title: String?
    public var subTitle: String?
    public var status: String?
}
```

Our API response:

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "custId":"1234",
      "type":"premium",
      "totalCount":"100",
      "msgList":[ 
         { 
            "id":"1",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         },
         { 
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         }
      ],
      "categoryCount":"50"
   }
}
```

How I can extract `msgList` array from JSON response and decode to `Message` model.

Something like only passing `list` data/json:

> let responseMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode([Message.self], from:
>   list)

Appreciate your help and suggestion!

Thanks

Comment: *Something like only passing list data/json*. That's not possible with standard `Decodable`. You have to decode always from the top (the dictionary with key `data`) or write a custom `init` method. [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift) can generate the structs for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the payload structure.

```
struct Data: Decodable {
    struct Payload: Decodable {
        let msgList: [Message]
    }

    let data: Payload
}
```

Decode JSON using JSONDecoder.

```
let responseMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode([Message.self], from: list)
```

messageList can access using : `responseMessage.data.msgList`

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite easy but you need to decode the full JSON object unless you want to start overriding the `init(from decoder:)` method and doing some stuff manually.

Trying to pull out just the messages array from the JSON would be more hassle than it's worth.

```
import UIKit

let jsonData = """
{
   "data":{
      "custId":"1234",
      "type":"premium",
      "totalCount":"100",
      "msgList":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         }
      ],
      "categoryCount":"50"
   }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct Root: Decodable {
    let data: Customer
}

struct Customer: Decodable {
    let custId: String
    let type: String
    let totalCount: String
    let msgList: [Message]
}

public struct Message: Decodable, Encodable {
    public var id: String?
    public var title: String?
    public var subTitle: String?
    public var status: String?
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: jsonData!)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can access the messages like this:

```
let messages = result.data.msgList
```

Comment: @LeoDabus as stated in the question.. "Framework internal Message model which we can't modify:". The Message struct is defined in a framework, not users code.

Comment: no worries leo, we all miss some things at times :)

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this:

```
// MARK: - Root
struct Root: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let custID, type, totalCount: String
    let msgList: [MsgList]
    let categoryCount: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case custID = "custId"
        case type, totalCount, msgList, categoryCount
    }
}

// MARK: - MsgList
struct MsgList: Codable {
    let id, title, subTitle, status: String
}
```

Then to load your data:

```
let list: [String : Any] = [:] // load data accordingly...
if let responseMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: list)
{
    // responseMessage.data.msgList
}
```

Class names are just an example, feel free to rename them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let str = """

{
   "data":{
      "custId":"1234",
      "type":"premium",
      "totalCount":"100",
      "msgList":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "title":"Main Title",
            "subTitle":"Sub title",
            "status":"R"
         }
      ],
      "categoryCount":"50"
   }
}
"""

        do {

            let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:Data(str.utf8))

            print(res.list)
        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }


    }

}
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let list : [Message]
    struct AnyCodingKey : CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int?
        init(_ codingKey: CodingKey) {
            self.stringValue = codingKey.stringValue
            self.intValue = codingKey.intValue
        }
        init(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
            self.intValue = nil
        }
        init(intValue: Int) {
            self.stringValue = String(intValue)
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var con = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self)
        con = try! con.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AnyCodingKey.self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"data"))
        let res = try! con.decode([Message].self, forKey: AnyCodingKey(stringValue:"msgList"))
        self.list = res       
    }
}


struct Message: Codable {
    let id,title,subTitle,status: String? 
}
```