# How to keep a flexible structure when using Codable in Swift

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

I've got a API response structure, representing a user object, that looks like this:

```
{
    "statuscode": 200,
    "response_type": 3,
    "errormessage": null,
    "detailresponse": {
        "id": "2",
        "shopifyautosync": null,
        "platformfeepercentage": null,
        "invited": null,
        "requiresyoutubesocialmediaupdate": 1,
        // Other properties ...
}
```

I'm using JSONDecoder().decode to decode to following structures:

```swift
import Foundation

class Response: Decodable {
    var statuscode: Int?
    var response_type: Int?
    // Other properties
    var detailresponse: User?
}

import Foundation

class User: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var street: String?
    var supporturl: String?
    var verifiedaccount: Int?
    var showfeatureupdatemodal: Int?
    var admin: Int?
    var email: String?
    // Other properties
}
```

Here's how I then decode:

```swift
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
```

My main problem now is that the Response class' detailresponse property is hard-wired to a User struct. However, I need a little flexibility in my setup, 
as the detailresponse will, of course, carry other data structures when calling different endpoints (e.g. a cooperation object instead of a user object).

Is there an elegant way to keep the detailresponse inside the Response class flexible instead of hard-wiring it? Or a generally better approach to the problem instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of generics

```
class Response<T:Decodable>: Decodable {
    var statuscode: Int?
    var response_type: Int?
    // Other properties
    var detailresponse: T?
}
```

Then

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response<User>.self, from: jsonData)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for generics:

```
class Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
   var statuscode: Int?
   var response_type: Int?
   // Other properties
   var detailresponse: T?
}
```

Note there is little reason to make the properties mutable. They should be `let`. Also, a `struct` would probably be a better choice here. And I think there should be less optionals since this is supposed to be a success response.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt help!
Can you let me know why a struct would be better than class here?

Comment: @BernhardEngl It's lightweight. I would always prefer `struct`, unless I need class semantics or inheritance, especially for immutable data types.

Comment: Thanks, understood. Also tried to follow your advice on making properties immutable. However, as soon as I declare one of them "let", I'm getting an error in my init method: "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties". Not sure how to ship around that.