# Flattened objects in JSON file to nested object structure in Swift

Tags: swift, codable

Given a JSON object with nested object structure that looks like this:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Adam",
            "age":25
         },
         "address":{
            "city":"Stockholm",
            "country":"Sweden"
         }
      },
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Lilly",
            "age":24
         },
         "address":{
            "city":"Copenhagen",
            "country":"Denmark"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can one implement correct `Decodable` implementation for an object that looks like this.

```
struct User {
  struct Address {
    let city: String
    let country: String
  }

  let name: String
  let age: Int
  let address: Address
}
```

Notice that the Swift struct contains a nested struct `Address`, while the JSON object has `address` in a separate object. Is it possible to create the `Decodable` implementation that handles this scenario?

I've tried various approaches, but all of them included creation of intermediary objects that would later map to the `User` struct. Is it possible to create an implementation that doesn't involve creation of these intermediary objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode a nested JSON struct with Swift Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom decoder so that you don't have to create the other objects.

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let address: Address


    struct Address: Decodable {
        let city: String
        let country: String
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user
        case address
    }

    enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case age
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let user = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: UserKeys.self, forKey: .user)
        name = try user.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        age = try user.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        address = try container.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)

    }
}
```

So putting your data into a playground

```
let data = """
{
   "users":[
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Adam",
            "age":25
         },
         "address":{
            "city":"Stockholm",
            "country":"Sweden"
         }
      },
      {
         "user":{
            "name":"Lilly",
            "age":24
         },
         "address":{
            "city":"Copenhagen",
            "country":"Denmark"
         }
      }
   ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

You can decode like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode([String:[User]].self, from: data)
```

Or you can create a Users struct so that you don't have to deal with dictionaries

```
struct Users: Decodable {
    let users: [User]
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decoder.decode(Users.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to flatten the `struct` using computed properties like this:

```
struct User: Codable {
    struct UserDetail: Codable {
        let name: String
        let age: Int
    }
    struct Address: Codable {
        let city: String
        let country: String
    }

    let user: UserDetail
    let address: Address

    var name: String { user.name}
    var age: Int { user.age }
    var city: String { address.city }
    var country: String { address.country }
}
print(user.name, user.age, user.city, user.country) // all the properties accessible within User struct
```

Comment: Not really, the problem I'd like to solve is how to actually decode this JSON object into the Swift struct that has another nested struct inside it.

Comment: You could use a custom decoder init method for that. You could use @Andrew's method or flatten everything using computed property to base struct like I did.

Comment: Upvoting because this solved my specific problem, if not OPs